VirtualBox machine does not start reliably
My host machine runs Ubuntu 24.04 and my guest O.S. in VirtualBox 7.0.22 is the same Ubuntu 24.04. I installed it without any problem, made few customization and installed a couple of applications. I rebooted several times with no issues.
I did this yesterday. Today, when I start the virtual machine it does not run anymore and this is the error:

In these weeks I started from scratch other three times and all went fine until it suddenly does not start anymore.
How is it possible? What should I check to stop wasting dozen of hours?
Some more details for the VM:

32 GB of RAM
16 CPUs
I always shut down the machine, I never suspend it

Here the full log.

There are a number of issues that can cause this to happen, but it generally is seen (in my experience) when one of the following conditions are met: (0) the VM is waking from suspend rather than a cold boot / (1) the VM has an insufficient amount of CPU dedicated to it while the host is doing something / (2) the VM display is not keeping up with the boot messages / (3) the host has a real-time kernel in place. Issues (1) and (2) can result in intermittent situations like yours. Issue (3) has RCU issues in the VM almost 90% of the time. Your boot logs may have more details.

@matigo thanks for the hint. I've updated the question. I'm running the standard Ubuntu 24.04 kernel, so I guess I'm not using a real-time kernel

I experience the same issue. If I Reset the VM, then it eventually boots. Sometimes it takes 3-4 attempts. Once I can login, it is stable and works reliably.
Host OS: Windows 11 Professional 64bit
Host CPU: Intel 12900HK (NOT affected by the CPU issues)
Host RAM: 64GB
It is quite stable, everything else works. The VM receives 24GB RAM and 8 CPU cores. What is unclear how the physical cores (which are not heterogenous) are allocated to the VM. Can try with less or more virtual CPUs.

I have been having the same issue on Windows 11 host with Ubuntu 24.04 guest currently running Linux kernel 6.8.8-50-generic.
I don't know if it is related but I get errors about vboxadd.service failing to start during boot.
